# Annotation-based wiring in Spring for only part of a collection

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a project where the pre-existing code has lots of manually setup and wired together classes done in the main method - seems like a perfect example of something Spring is good at replacing. There are several objects that share a parent class, Widget. Each Widget contains a list of other widgets it depends on.

As an example, if you were to write this in code, it would something like:

```
class Widget{ void addDependency(Widget w}{..}}

class A extends Widget{...}
...
class G extends Widget{...}

A a = new A();
...
G g = new G();

a.addDependency(b);
b.addDependency(c);
b.addDependency(d);
b.addDependency(f);
c.addDependency(g);
```

You obviously can't just have an @Autowired collection of Widgets, because then you'll get a collection of all the Widgets. Is there a way for @Autowired to filter out so it only gets instances of certain subtypes?

There are two ways of doing this that I don't like. The first would be to wire in all non-widget beans, and wire the Widget collections together after the context is loaded.The other way of doing this is by using @Resource to wire in the ApplicationContext and using a @PostConstructor to get what you need from the ApplicationContext. Both seem inelegant, is there another way?

Comment: Have you looked at SpEL? It has features for filtering collections....

Comment: Is the order of the dependencies important?

Comment: No, the order is not important: {C,D,F} is the same as {F,D,C}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it similar to how @Matt is doing it but I might consider creating a custom [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) but Matt's way I think is safer.

Then I would create a custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Dependencies {
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

I would put the annotation on each one of the widgets

```
@Dependencies({WidgetB.class,WidgetC.class})
public class WidgetA extends Widget {
}
```

Then you'll do @Matt bean finding (you should checkout [Spring's BeanFactoryUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryUtils.html)) pulling out the dependecies from `bean.getClass().getAnnotation(Dependencies.class)`.

Instead of the annotation you could do a property on the beans to list there deps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include a sample of what you've tried in spring with the @PostConstruct, this is what i would be doing.

```
@Component
public WidgetBuilderComponent {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void populate() {
        A a = a();
        for (B b: context.getBeansOfType(B.class).values()) {
            a.addDependency(b);
        }
    }
}
```

You would have similar classes for the other types.  If you need multiple instances of a given type, just create multiple @Bean methods, and be sure to populate each one appropriately in the @PostConstruct method.  Note that classes like this are not able to be placed more than once in the same context.

You could always replace this with a FactoryBean + InitializingBean which would accomplish the same thing, though it would be a bit more re-usable.

Another alternative would be to use use the @Component simply for the wiring, letting your widgets construct themselves and not worry about wiring.

```
@Component
public WidgetPopulatorComponent {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void populate() {
        for (A a: context.getBeansOfType(A.class).values()) {
            for (B b: context.getBeansOfType(B.class).values()) {
                a.addDependency(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```